# Protractor filter, how to find elements within filtered elements

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

Below is some shortened HTML that I have, and an attempt at some protractor code.

What I'm trying to do, is do a click on an i element. I'd like to be able to do the click, based on what the ID is, which is in a sibling element.

The below code doesnt work. I've also tried doing a filter inside a filter, and everything I try is causing errors. Can anyone help please? The error I get with this attempt is "Cannot read property element of undefined.

Can anyone help with this please? Have spent a lot of time on this so far!

Thanks.

```
element.all(by.repeater('data in ctrl.data')).filter(function(elem){
    return elem.element(by.css('div.case-info span')).getText() == id
}).then(function(filteredElements){
    filteredElements.first().element(by.css('i.fa')).click();
});




<div ng-repeater="data in ctrl.data">
    <div class="case-info">
        <span>AN ID HERE</span>
        <div>Other stuff here thats not really relevant</div>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-red"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: are you accessing ```e1``` or ```elem``` inside filter?

Comment: Its actually elem I'm accessing.... That was just a typo as I typed it into here, Editted and fixed it now.

Comment: ok , ```getText()``` returns promise you have to resolve that first!

Answer (score 8):

Here's what worked for me in the end, with help from the above two answers...

```
element.all(by.repeater('data in ctrl.data')).filter(function(elem){
    return elem.element(by.css('div.case-info span')).getText().then(function(text){
        return text === id;
    });
}).first().element(by.css('i.fa')).click();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You've almost got it... as @igniteram1 said, you just need to wait for `getText()` to return it's promise (though I would advise against using an `expect` in the loop). Something like this...

```
element.all(by.repeater('data in ctrl.data')).filter(function(elem){
    return elem.element(by.css('div.case-info span')).getText().then(function(text){
        return text === id;
    }) ;
}).then(function(filteredElements){
    filteredElements.element(by.css('i.fa')).click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it. The above didn't quite work for me, but your answer did help me make progress and figure out the solution. With the above, I was getting the error: filteredElements.first() is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this -

```
element.all(by.repeater('data in ctrl.data')).filter(function(elem){
return elem.element(by.css('div.case-info span')).getText().then(function(text){
expect(text).toEqual(id); // your id here
}).then(function(filteredElements){
filteredElements.first().element(by.css('i.fa')).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an XPath. It will be faster and easier to maintain:

```
var xpath = "//div[@ng-repeater='data in ctrl.data'][.//span[text()='" + id + "']]/i";
element(by.xpath(xpath)).click();
```

Comment: Huh?  Xpath is the slowest and hardest to maintain

Comment: Yes I agree with @Gunderson, imagine if the browser's DOM changes due to some javascript functions, there are high chances locators with xpath will fail. Xpath should be the last option.

Comment: @Gunderson, in this specific case, a short XPath is easier to maintain compared to multiple lines of code. Moreover, executing an XPath is less expansive than a calls to the browser. There is a minimum a 4 calls to the browser when using `filter` compared to one with an XPath. So yes it will be faster.

Comment: @igniteram1, if the DOM changes, filtering with some code is as much exposed to failure as an XPath. There are some specific cases where an XPath is the best option, and finding an element containing some text is one of it.

Comment: Florent , I see your point but how xpath would wait for angular objects to load without promises?

Comment: @Vishal Aggarwal, it will do so the same way as with a CSS selector. The locating mechanism is implemented in the driver and the waiter in protractor.

Comment: @Florent , let me understand why your code example will not fail as it is not waiting for angular objects to load and promises to be resolved as we do with .then ??? How are you making sure in your code that all promises are resolved before you try finding the element in DOM??

Comment: @Vishal Aggarwal, resolving a promise with `.then` is only required if you need a command's result like with `.getText()`. The execution flow of protractor automatically waits for a command to finish before executing the next one.